# Regex JS no output in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Assuming this string

```
123_4,56776_17,_,99997_1,_,87969_3,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,456_9
```

My desired output is:

```
123_4,56776_17,99997_1,87969_3,456_9
```

My regex appears to do the trick here https://regex101.com/r/dXtrph/1 :

```
(?<=)\d+_\d+(?=)
```

But no output in JS code. Is there an issue with the underscore?

```
var strng = '123_4,56776_17,_,99997_1,_,87969_3,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,456_9';
var rgx = /(?<=)\d+_\d+(?=);  
var outstrng = strng.match(rgx).join(',');
Write(outstrng);
```

Comment: You do not need the empty lookarounds. And you missed the trailing `/g`. `var rgx = /\d+_\d+/g;`. Please make sure you also check [code generator page](https://regex101.com/r/dXtrph/1/codegen?language=javascript) when you are not sure what the regex looks like in the code.

Comment: That worked, thank you! :-)